# Не получается добавить метку в яндекс карты api 3.0

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

В документации черт ногу сломит, пытаюсь добавить слой для меток пишет YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer is not defined
Может кто работал уже с 3 версией?

Код ниже рабочий но без меток

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/3.0/?apikey=ваш-апи-ключ&lang=ru_RU"></script>
<script>
  ymaps3.ready.then(init);

  function init() {
    const map = new ymaps3.YMap(document.getElementById('map'), {
      location: {
        center: [37.64, 55.76],
        zoom: 7
      }
    });
    const layer = new ymaps3.YMapDefaultSchemeLayer();
    map.addChild(layer);


  }
</script>
<div id="map" class="mb-4" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
```

При добавлении вот этого кода из документации метки не появляются

```
map.addChild(new YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer()); // В этом слое будут маркеры.
// DOM-элемент должен быть создан заранее, но его содержимое можно задать в любой момент.
const content = document.createElement('section');
const marker = new YMapMarker({
    coordinates: [37.588144, 55.733842],
    draggable: true
}, content);
map.addChild(marker);
content.innerHTML = '<h1>Этот заголовок можно переносить</h1>';
```

Comment: Разобрался сам. Нужно делать приписку ymaps3. перед YMapDefalutFeaturesLayer и YMapMarker в добавлении слоя и метки

Comment: Напишите ответ.